# Angular Rxjs observable wont fire again after unsubscribed

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs6

I am listening to socket with Observable and subscribing it in one of my component. If I don't unsubscribe it in `ngOnDestroy`, when I go to that component again it will fire N times(N being the number of times I switch back to that component) but if I unsubscribe it in `ngOnDestroy` then it will listen first time I go to that component and when I go to other component and return back, it will not fire.

```js
//in socket service
updateOrder() {
  if (!this.socket.connected)
    this.socket.connect();
  let observable = new Observable < any > (observer => {
    this.socket.on('test', (data) => {
      observer.next(data); //going into here
    });
    return () => {
      this.socket.disconnect();
    };
  })
  return observable;
}
```

In constructor of listening component

```js
this.orderSubscriber = this.socketService.updateOrder().subscribe(data => {
  console.log('socket fired', data);
})
```

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.orderSubscriber.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: You probably need to do some sort of `socket.connect` within `updateOrder`. It looks like it is done somewhere else and when you call `socket.disconnect` it will never emit values again.

Comment: this line is causing issue `this.socket.disconnect();` i.e. you are disconnecting socket when you unsubscribe, so next time when you come you need to open connection again

Comment: can you share your code somewhere , it will be helpful

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner @PranayRana  Thank you for the reply, I used `if (!this.socket.connected) this.socket.connect();` at the start of `updateOrder` and the component is now firing only one time like intended but `observer.next(data);` inside `updateOrder` is getting called same like before. Is it normal?

Comment: @BibekGurung it is probably normal because you are opening a socket which brings in bunch of data over time. It should get called multiple times.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner but I am emitting `test` event only one time from server.

Comment: Put your updated code in the question and let's check again

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Using `socket.removeListener('test')` rather than `socket.disconnect()` solved. Thank you people who guided me to the problem.

```js
//in socket service
updateOrder() {
  let observable = new Observable < any > (observer => {
    this.socket.on('test', (data) => {
      observer.next(data);
    });
    return () => {
      this.socket.removeListener('test')
    };
  })
  return observable;
}
```